# Formatting JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to build some JSON on the in PHP. I am brand new to PHP and know very little about it. Currently, I have the following:

```
$json = '{"content":{"person":{"name":"$name", "email":"$email"}, "title":"$subject", "description": { "body": "$details" }}}';
```

`$name`, `$email`, `$subject`, and `$details` are all variables that have been defined previously. If I print out $json using the code above, I get the following:

```
{"content":{"person":{"name":"$name", "email":"$email"}, "title":"$subject", "description": { "body": "$details" }}}'
```

In other words, my variables didn't replace the placeholders in the string. How do I build some JSON using variables as key values?

Thank you!

Comment: Build an array containing the data and structure you desire. Then use json_encode() to convert it to JSON.

Comment: And for future:  [PHP Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, double quotes and single quotes do different things; you can only use variables inline within strings if you use double quotes:

```
$test = 'world';
echo 'Hello $test!'; // Prints: Hello $test!
echo "Hello $test!"; // Prints: Hello world!
```

If you use double quotes to surround your json string, you'd need to escape all the double quotes that you have inside it:

```
$json = "{\"content\":{\"person\":{\"name\":\"$name\", \"email\":\"$email\"}, \"title\":\"$subject\", \"description\": { \"body\": \"$details\" }}}";
```

**Alternative Method**

NB: Are you familiar with PHP arrays? PHP has the function `json_encode` that converts arrays into JSON strings - doing that might make your code easier (especially if your json string is going to get larger / more complex at any point)

```
$json = json_encode(array
(
    "content" => array
    (
        "person"      => array
        (
            "name"  => $name,
            "email" => $email
        ),
        "title"       => $subject,
        "description" => array
        (
            "body" => $details
        )
    )
));
```

Either of these solutions should give `$json` the value you expect

Hope this helps :) x

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the best way would be to build up your data into the structure that you want and use json_encode to fix it.

The reason that you particular string is not replacing the variables is because it is enclosed by ' instead of "

```
$json = "{\"content\":{\"person\":{\"name\":\"$name\", \"email\":\"$email\"}, \"title\":\"$subject\", \"description\": { \"body\": \"$details\" }}}'\";
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 1):

```
$content = json_encode(array(
'content' => array(
     'person' => array(
         'name' => $name,
         'email' => $email,
         'title' => $subject,
         'description' => array(
             'body' => $details
             )
         )
   )
);
echo $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is always very helpful, check out the ones for strings, here it will explain how you can and cannot use variables in single quoted or double quoted strings.

**[Documentation on Strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)**

**An easier solution is to use an array and json_encode it which will output what you have in your question:**

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'content' => array(
        'person' => array(
            'name'  => $name,
            'email' => $email,
        ),
        'title' => $subject,
        'description' => array(
            'body' => $details,
        ),
    ),
);

$json = json_encode($array);
```